# Set background-color and background-image using CSS in Eclipse 4

Tags: css, eclipse-rcp, background-image, background-color, e4

Is it possible to apply both background-color and background-image using CSS in Eclipse 4? I am trying with the following example and all I can get is either the correct background or the image repeated many times within the window with the black background:

```
Shell {
  background-color: gradient linear rgb(0,206,209) rgb(0,255,127);
  background-image: url('./image.png');
}
```

Additionally, I would like to have the image appear once in the upper-right corner of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible currently.

The gradient background is drawn by creating a background image for the control, so any background image you set will override this.

Control background images are tiled and there is no control over this.